# How to remove issues from SonarQube on excluded files that once were analyzed?

Tags: sonarqube

In a SonarQube (v6.4) project I recently excluded a set of files but SonarQube still reports open issues for them.

Browsing the list of code for the folders shows that zero lines of code, but a number of issues exist. These issues can be opened, so they still exist.

How can these issues for files that are now excluded be removed?

Answer (score 1):

Excluding files from coverage calculations is a separate step from excluding them from certain rules. For that, see [Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues), which allows you to say "ignore issues from rule X on file Y".

Comment: Now trying this, but from what I read it's more like filtering them. Setting a rule with a _File Path Pattern_ on _Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria_ crashes the analysis with a `java.lang.IllegalStateException`. Yesterday I ended up deleting the project and starting fresh.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the analyzer? If not, please upgrade. If so, please report the crash on the [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube)

Comment: Same here - any idea how to actually get rid of them? I am using the very latest version of the analysers